# Silero Silero Silero there is an error in the code. the code used to work, but now it doesn't

Tags: python-3.x

It worked before, but then for some reason the previous code was not saved and I'm writing it again. now it doesn't work in a new folder.error appeared I don't know what to do`
This is a code:

```
import time, torch, speech_recognition as sr, sounddevice as sd, random

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya'
put_ac = True
put_yoo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4_silero-models_master',
                          model = 'silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)
q=random.randint(0, 1)
if q==0:
    text = "Пятница готова к работе"
else:
    text = "Здравствуйте! Слушаю Вас"
audio = model.apply_tts(text = text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_ac,
                        put_yo=put_yoo)
sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio)/sample_rate)
sd.stop()
def main():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Говорите...")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source=source, duration=0.5)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
            print("[log] Распознано: ", query)
    except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
        main()
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        main()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        main()
    
    
    if query == "привет":
        text = "привет, я готова к работе"
        audio = model.apply_tts(text = text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_ac,
                        put_yo=put_yoo)
        sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
        time.sleep(len(audio)/sample_rate)
        sd.stop()
    

while 5<6:
    main()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is a mistake:

```
File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\fri\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4_silero-models_master',
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 563, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 207, in _get_cache_or_reload
    repo_owner, repo_name, ref = _parse_repo_info(github)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 143, in _parse_repo_info    
    repo_owner, repo_name = repo_info.split('/')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

It worked before, but then for some reason the previous code was not saved and I'm writing it again. now it doesn't work in a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Function `torch.hub.load` expects a `/` separated argument : `{repo_owner}/{repo_name}` in your case `snakers4/silero-models`. You currently pass `snakers4_silero-models_master`.

The above is judging by this piece of code:

```
def _parse_repo_info(github):
    if ':' in github:
        repo_info, ref = github.split(':')
    else:
        repo_info, ref = github, None
    repo_owner, repo_name = repo_info.split('/')
    # [....]
```

[Code link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/de600508018ee208dd8f65532d53bd59e14f85aa/torch/hub.py#L143)

Comment: Sorry for the stupidity, but where to put it in the code?

Comment: 10th row! `model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4_silero-models_master',`, instead of `snakers4_silero-models_master` try `snakers4_silero/models_master`

Comment: No. It throws a 404 error. urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I was wrong in the comment, but not in the answer: `repo_or_dir ="snakers4/silero-models"` is the correct argument. Does not throw 404

Comment: File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\fri\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4_silero/models_master',
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 563, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 230, in _get_cache_or_reload
    _validate_not_a_forked_repo(repo_owner, repo_name, ref)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 189, in _validate_not_a_forked_repo
    response = json.loads(_read_url(Request(url, headers=headers)))
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 172, in _read_url

Comment: File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: entire error output

Comment: I program in vs code because pycharm doesn't work.

Comment: You are still using `snakers4_silero/models_master`, try using `snakers4/silero-models` instead

Comment: print("thank you"*100000000)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU

Comment: ? What is it..?

Comment: I don't have enough level